# output of hostname -A

Tags: hostname

`hostname -A` displays all FQDNs of the machine, according to the manual of `hostname`.

Here is my PC in local home net.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ hostname -A    
hwy 
debian8@hwy:~$ hostname -d    
local
debian8@hwy:~$ hostname -f
hwy.local
```

Why is the output info of `hostname -A` not `hwy.local`?
-A, --all-fqdns Displays,but hwy is not fqdn at all!!

Answer (score 1):

No reverse DNS entry set?

> -A, --all-fqdns
>   Displays all FQDNs of the machine. This option enumerates all configured network addresses on all configured network interfaces, and translates them to DNS domain names. Addresses that cannot be translated (i.e. because they do not have an appropriate reverse DNS entry) are skipped. Note that different addresses may resolve to the same name, therefore the output may contain duplicate entries. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

[# man hostname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname)

Comment: -A, --all-fqdns Displays,but hwy is not fqdn!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean but here is some info from man page:

"Therefore it **depends on the configuration** (usually in /etc/host.conf) how you can change it. Usually (if the hosts file is parsed before **DNS or NIS)** you can change it in /etc/hosts." regarding the FQDN.